# or clause in datomic

Tags: clojure, datomic

I am working with `or` clause in datomic.
I know that using `or` in this query I get the users with `:user/first-name "Mia"` and users with `:user/first-name "Wallace"`.

```
(d/q
  '[:find ?u
    :where
    (or [?u :user/first-name "Mia"]
        [?u :user/last-name "Wallace"])]
  (d/db conn))
```

But I would like a clause that works like Clojure's `or`. That's it, I want users with :user/first-name "Mia" and if there is not, I want to find the ones with  `:user/last-name "Lucas"`. Is it possible to do that in one query? I know that I can do it with two queries.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that using either a [Collection Binding](https://docs.datomic.com/on-prem/query/query.html#collection-binding) or a [Relation Binding](https://docs.datomic.com/on-prem/query/query.html#relation-binding).  From the docs:

> A collection binding binds a single variable to multiple values passed
> in as a collection. This can be used to ask "or" questions, i.e. what
> releases are associated with either Paul McCartney or George Harrison?

```
;; query
[:find ?release-name
 :in $ [?artist-name ...]
 :where [?artist :artist/name ?artist-name]
        [?release :release/artists ?artist]
        [?release :release/name ?release-name]]

;; inputs
db, ["Paul McCartney" "George Harrison"]

;; result
#{["My Sweet Lord"] 
  ["Electronic Sound"]
  ["Give Me Love (Give Me Peace on Earth)"] 
  ["All Things Must Pass"]
  ...}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this has the same effect as `or-join`, returns results for both "Paul McCartney" and "George Harrison"